# should i avoid long chained expresion in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

is writing long-chained code in kotlin like this considered to be clean and easy to understand?

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                setContentView(binding.root)
              
                binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener {
//check in one line if costOfService text is not null and different from 0
//before calling displayTip
                    binding.costOfService.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull()?.takeIf { it != 0.0 }?.let {
                        displayTip(calculateTip(it))
                    }
                }
            }
```

> This function calculate the tip based on the user entry

```
private fun calculateTip(tip: Double): Double {
    return when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        binding.optionTwentyPercent.id -> 0.20 * tip
        binding.optionEighteenPercent.id -> 0.18 * tip
        else -> 0.15 * tip
    }.also {
        if (binding.roundUpSwitch.isChecked)
            kotlin.math.ceil(it)
    }
}
```

> this function change the text in tipResult view

```
 private fun displayTip(tip: Double) {
        val formattedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
        binding.tipResult.text = getString(R.string.tip_amount, formattedTip)
    }
}
```

Comment: What about providing the description for the use of your code?

Comment: sorry, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, that is not very readable. Don't be afraid to break code up into multiple lines if it's clearer. And if you create local variables, you don't have to resort to the `?.let` pattern to deal with nullability. Smart-casting will allow your code to be more readable than that. In this case, since you're ignoring 0 anyway, you can make the default 0 instead of null to simplify it. This is how I would break it up:

```
binding.calculateButton.setOnClickListener {
    val enteredValue = binding.costOfService.text.toString().toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
    if (enteredValue != 0.0) {
        displayTip(calculateTip(enteredValue))
    }
}
```

By the way, I think you have a bug in your `calculateTip` function. The part in the `also` block is rounding up the number but then throwing away the rounded number and returning the original. You could use `let` or `run` instead, but I consider this scope function abuse. Just because you can chain scope functions onto other expressions doesn't mean you should. It creates poor readability. Here's how I would write that function:

```
private fun calculateTip(total: Double): Double = with(binding) {
    val fraction = when (tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
        optionTwentyPercent.id -> 0.20
        optionEighteenPercent.id -> 0.18
        else -> 0.15
    }
    val tip = fraction * total
    if (roundUpSwitch.isChecked) ceil(tip) else tip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://proandroiddev.com/noisy-code-with-kotlin-scopes-331c632739de
read this blog
the problem with scope is that it will dual reference to same variable

Comment: I like the comments in this article.

Comment: Can you please expand your summary of the blog? Link-only answers are [discouraged on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/201031).